# Asp.net ajax with mvc2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am calling a ajax method as below

```
 var srchText = "Chicago";


 $.ajax({
    url: "/Ajax/GetCities",
    data: "{'srchText' : '" + srchText + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
    success: function (data) {
        cityList = data.d;
    }
});
```

The url is pointing to a MVC controller, as below,

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCities(string srchText)
    {
        List<City> result = new List<City>();
        EventsBIZ objBIZ = new EventsBIZ();
        result = objBIZ.ToList<City>(objBIZ.GetCities(srchText));
        return this.Json(new GetEventsResponse() { d = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

There is something wrong with the code, that the method is called successfully, but the srchText is coming as null. Please help me to figure out wat went wrong. Thanks in advance

Adding the request tracked from firebug.
[image: FireBug Net monitor]

Comment: What do your routes look like? Couldn't you be using ("/Ajax/GetCities/" + srchText)?

Comment: updated with the firebug screenshot. I want to send it as json object, gradually i want to make the input as a complex class. So sending it through the url wont help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because by default ASP.NET MVC 2 doesn't *understand* `JSON` requests. There is nothing built-in that allows you to send a JSON formatted request and that this request is parsed back to a strongly typed action argument. This functionality is built-in by default starting from ASP.NET MVC 3. Take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx). You will need to implement a `JsonValueProviderFactory` if you want to make this work under ASP.NET MVC 2.

Also instead of:

```
data: "{'srchText' : '" + srchText + "'}",
```

you should use:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ srchText: srchText }),
```

The `JSON.stringify` is native for modern browsers, and for older you might need to include [`json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Another possibility if you don't want to implement a `JsonValueProviderFactory` is to use a standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request which the default model binder can understand:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/GetCities',
    data: { srchText: srchText },
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
    success: function (data) {
        cityList = data.d;
    }
});
```

Comment: U hit the nail on the head. One more question. When i change the input to an object instead of a string, and am using the default model binder, sending a normal javascript object is coming to the server. But the properties of the object are defalted(as in int to 0 and string to null). Any idea how to send the object without jsonvalueproviderfactory?

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to send `srchText` as `json` becuase you will just send a string  so can send it as query string

try this

```
 var srchText = "Chicago";


$.ajax({
url: "/Ajax/GetCities",
data: 'srchText=' + srchText ,
type: "POST",
async: false,
dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
success: function (data) {
    cityList = data.d;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're passing valid JSON, try using:

```
data: {"srchText" : srchText},
```