# "POST" data with jquery ajax and MVC2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC2, and I'm trying to send data with jquery ajax.

There is my JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Data",
    data: { processName: "MyProc", startDate: "2015-08-01 16:00"},
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

And there is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Data(string processName, string startDate)
{
    int i = 1;
}
```

So my problem is that I DO get to `"int i=1;"` line in my controller,
BUT for some unknown reason - `processName` and `startDate` are both `null`.

Can someone please assist ?

Comment: Try adding this property to your ajax call: `contentType: 'application/json'` and wrapping the data in `JSON.stringify({ processName: "MyProc", startDate: "2015-08-01 16:00"})`

Comment: i copy all the code to my vs and seem working perfectly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that attribute is from WebAPI dll.. I cannot use it

Comment: Using JSON in MVC2 isn't straight-forward:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479534/asp-net-ajax-with-mvc2

Answer (score 1):

Try making a model and using that for the parameter in your action

```
  public class MyModel
{
    public string processName { get; set; }

    public string startDate { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Data(MyModel model)
    {
       int i = 1;
        //model.processName
        //model.startDate

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add content type and data type in your jquery code + stringify your data:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Data",
  data: JSON.stringify({ processName: "MyProc", startDate: "2015-08-01 16:00"}),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data) {
  }
});
```

Comment: Changed it to:
$.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "Data",
                      data: JSON.stringify({ processName: "MyProc", startDate: "2015-08-01 16:00"}),
                      dataType: "json",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      success: function(data) {
                      }
                    });

Comment: and I'm reaching "int i=1;" row, but STILL getting nulls in those two vars :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
                type: 'POST',
                data:  JSON.stringify({ processName: "MyProc", startDate: "2015-08-01 16:00"}),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (responseData) {
    }
    });
```